# How to run bundle install on gitlab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gitlab

Yesterday I updated gitlab 8.4.3 to 8.4.4, during upgrading I got an error related to permissions on Gemfile.lock and the upgrading process was interrupted.

Today, I cannot access my gitlab installation, I traced the error to a missing gem, when I run `gitlab-rails` I got

```
Could not find ruby-saml-1.1.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I try to run `sudo -u git -H bundle install` I got

```
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

How can I install this gem? Which is the correct way to run bundle install?

gitlab is installed/upgraded via apt-get.

**update: 2016-02-22**

Turns out that gitlab does not provides a `bundle install` command, the gems are included in the .deb file. So, all I needed to do was to skip the migrations, just install the new version, and then -once that all the files were correctly installed- run the migrations.

```
touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-migrations
apt-get dist-upgrade
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

***protip:*** When troubleshooting, make sure that everything is correctly installed then run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`; it can fix common issues.

Comment: are you using rbenv or rvm?

Comment: @faron I don't know. gitlab embeds its version of ruby and rails, I don't know how gitlab configures its own environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gitlab does not provides a `bundle install` command, the gems are included in the .deb file.

So, just install the new version (skip migrations) and then run the migrations.

```
touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-migrations
apt-get dist-upgrade
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: better scripts

---

Case 1.

```
image: ruby:2.1

# add bundle cache to 'vendor' for speeding up builds
cache:
  paths: 
    - vendor/

before_script:
  - bundle install --path vendor

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bundle exec <your_script>
  only:
    - master # the job 'deploy' will affect only the 'master' branch
```

Case 2: when you need a JS runtime

```
image: ruby:2.1

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  - bundle install --path vendor

cache:
  paths: 
    - vendor/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec <your_script>
  only:
    - master # the job 'deploy' will affect only the 'master' branch
```

---

- Official [doc](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html)
- Working examples: [Build Jekyll site with Bundler](https://gitlab.com/jekyll-themes/default-bundler) and [Build Middleman site with Bundler](https://gitlab.com/middleman-themes/middleman)